# Get content of iframe from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

everyone.
I created my page and inserted inside another page using IFrame. Now I'm trying to get whole text of that inserted page using pure javascript or jquery. Here's what I have now, but it doesn't work...

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFrameContents(){
   return $("#myframe").contents().find('body');
}
</script>
</head>

<form>
<input type="button" value="CodingForums" onClick="window.alert(getFrameContents())" />
</form>

<iframe id='myframe' src="http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/currency-rates/" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</html>
```

I've read also that there is some policy about accessing pages from different server. How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've read also that there is some policy about accessing pages from different server.

Yes there is and the policy says it's strictly forbidden.

> How can I do it properly?

Fetch it on the server-side. You might want to use a server-side cache too.

Comment: Why is it forbidden? I just want to read content of the loaded page. I can do it with broswer, why I can't do it with js?

Comment: because you can then inject the page, which means you can redirect it to whereever you wish, hijack it :)

Comment: @damluar There is a class of attacks called XSS (Cross-site scripting) when the attaker can execute script in a page's content. This way they can access cookies, session data etc. - Just imagine, you open gmail.com in a hidden iframe and read the visitors' emails.

Comment: @vbence Ok, agree. can I access this data if I write firefox plugin? here is a description of what I want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233397/get-content-of-page-including-iframe-from-firefox-plugin

Comment: @damluar Feel free to vote up or even accept answers if you think they were satisfying. - And yes, you can do anything from a firefox plugin (legal questions aside).

Answer (score 1):

Many people ask this question...

The best way people describe is (as i dont like iframes) but you need on iframe to collect the data and use `window.top....` to access the main page and pass it that way because `.contents()` is not supported by all browsers.