# Get content of page (including iframe) from firefox plugin

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser

everyone.
I'm trying to get data from some page, it's updated using javascript.
First, I tried to make java program and periodically get this page from server. But the values on the page were updated too slow.
So, I need to get content on the fly. Secondly, I tried to insert this page into my own and use js to get content. But security policy forbids this action.
The only option I have now is to write a plugin to firefox, for example. But will I have access to iframe data or it's also forbidden?

Comment: You certainly can do it. You can also listen to xmlhttprequests. Just to clarify, you want to gather data from/alter a page from a specific url? Not ajax (xmlhttprequest) data?

Comment: The data I need is here: http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/currency-rates/  All I need is to get numbers from this table and save it in file or DB. Can you advise some tutorial, I've never written plugins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But will I have access to iframe data or it's also forbidden?

Yes, you will have access. Firefox add-ons do not need to respect the normal security policies (depending on what and how they do things, of course).

**EDIT** (in response to OP comment)

Please see [Building an Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension) at Mozilla Developer Center for getting started.

You will need to listen to xmlhttprequests as the data in the currency rates table at http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/currency-rates/

You'll probably also want to look at http://www.ashita.org/howto-xhr-listening-by-a-firefox-addon/ for how to listen to the XHR requests.